# Using R to work with liteDB

Tags: r, litedb

I'm looking for a way to (conveniently) use R to access data stored in a LiteDB.
There does not seem to be a package but is there another way to make it accessible?

Comment: It doesn't appear to use ODBC & is .NET-based, so — in all practical sense (I know Mono / `dotnet` exists) — Windows-only (esp since the build of it fails on macOS … I just tried), and no REST API (I understand why that is, tho). What does "conveniently" mean? It seems to have a [decent command-line shell app](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/Shell). One approach would be to make a set of convenience functions to build queries/ops, write them to a file and `system()` (et al) exec the litedb shell executable with the `run` litedb shell op.

Answer (score 0):

This is long shot but, have you tried using the `DBI` package's generic `connect()` method?

```
con <- mongo(<table name>, url = <database_filename>)
```

I would try testing the MongoDB driver as its a NoSQL database. I don't expect this to work but I believe it's worth trying out.

The only other feasible alternative would be to export the data you need as a CSV file (or alternative) and import that data into R, `<readr::read_csv()>`.

If you really prefer to work with a database, then migrating to a SQLite database will allow you to use the RSQLite package to work with the data.

---

Or you could always try to write a driver for LiteDB to fit into the DBI package...